# rxjava2 - how to pass in a consumer as parameter

Tags: rx-java2

i am using the following rxjava dependencies in android:

```
 compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

and i am trying to create a method that will take in a observer as a paramter. I am having some issues i think its because this is rxjava2 so things are updated and im a little confused.

Let me show you what i want to accomplish:

```
private Subscription subscription = Scriptions.empty(); //this isn't working. how to set a empty observer IN RXJAVA2?

protected abstract Observable buildUseCaseObservable(); //RETROFIT WILL BUILD THE OBSERVABLE FOR ME SOMEWHERE ELSE


public void execute(Consumer UseCaseSubscriber){
    this.subscription = this.buildUseCaseObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber); //THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING , ERROR IS IN THE PHOTO
}

public void unsubscribe(){
    if(!subscription.isUnsubscribed()){
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Basically i am trying to create a method that will accept a observer/consumer as parameter and use that to update the UI after retrofit is done (being the observable).

**UPDATE**:
ok i changed it to disposables. now i'd like to store the disposable that i get back but its not working.

```
protected abstract Observable buildUseCaseObservable();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void execute(Observer UseCaseSubscriber){
        this.subscription = this.buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(){
        if(!subscription.isUnsubscribed()){
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

i am getting the following warning:

[image]

The reason i want to store the whole thing in a subscription (or whatever else you recommend) is so i can unsubscribe to it whenever i want.

but from the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscription):

> Because Reactive-Streams base interface, org.reactivestreams.Publisher defines the subscribe() method as void, Flowable.subscribe(Subscriber) no longer returns any Subscription (or Disposable). The other base reactive types also follow this signature with their respective subscriber types.

so how to save disposable so we can unsubscribe then ?

Comment: I suggest you read the entire wiki page as the answer is given in a section above you qouted: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber

Comment: Excellent . Your right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subscription` has been 'renamed' to `Disposable` with 2.x version. You can read the rxJava wiki explanation on this change [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscription).

so how to save disposable so we can unsubscribe then ? `Flowable.subscribe(Subscriber)` doesn't return disposable, but `Observable.subscribe(Subscriber)` does. If you don't need back-pressure, just cast your `Flowable` to `Observable` with `.toObservable()`.

Comment: Thanks changing it to disposable works but i updated my question can you help ? i need to store the entire thing in a subscription to unsubscribe afterwards